# Swift, выполнение кода при нажатии на Touch ID

Tags: swift, touch

На устройсте macbook air m2, скачал открыл Xcode, для начала просто вывел "hi", всё вывелось отлично, когда попробовал сделать что то по сложнее, накидал функцию которая должна выводить текст если нажат модуль Touch ID, запускаю код, нажимаю Touch ID, но ничего не происходит, если кто-то с подобным работал, подскажите

```
import LocalAuthentication

class TouchIDManager {
    let context = LAContext()

    func authenticateWithTouchID() {
        var error: NSError?

        guard context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) else {
            if let error = error {
                print("Не удалось выполнить проверку поддержки аутентификации по отпечатку пальца: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("Устройство не поддерживает аутентификацию по отпечатку пальца")
            }
            return
        }

        let reason = "Аутентификация по отпечатку пальца для выполнения действия"
        context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason) { success, evaluateError in
            if success {
                print("Аутентификация по отпечатку пальца прошла успешно")
            } else {
                if let error = evaluateError {
                    print("Ошибка аутентификации по отпечатку пальца: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                } else {
                    print("Аутентификация по отпечатку пальца не удалась")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Видео как я это делаю](https://dropmefiles.com/MWTFg)